# why does not eclipse PDT syntax checker underline undefined function? Missing on-the-fly code analysis in PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, code-analysis, eclipse-pdt, on-the-fly

I am using Juno - created a PHP project and having PHP perspective.

```
<?php
undefined_function();
?>
```

when I run this code i got this: Call to undefined function: undefined_function()

However, the eclipse PDT syntax checker did not underline the undefined function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob You did not understand the question. Read the _title_.

Comment: It is a big problem to access all available definition inside a php project, since php 'applications' and the like are very loosely bound together. In many cases it is simply not clear if such function is really not defined/implemented somewhere else.

Comment: How is Eclipse supposed to know the function is not defined?  Maybe it's defined in some other file that gets included or autoloaded.  There's no way you could reliably discover errors like that before runtime.

Comment: @GordonM PHPStorm defines this out well. Try it :)

Comment: @GordonM the OP means if the function is not defined within the project (including external dependencies) then the IDE should consider it undefined and signal the developer about that. PHPStorm does just that and the help provided is simply incredible.